# upload image to server without compress image

Tags: android

I want to upload image to server without compress it because I am compressing the image in another function and than sending the image to **uploadtoserver** function.

here is my code to upload the image to server but i dont understand how to upload the image to server without compress it.

```
public String uploadtoserver(String imgPathm){
    //int flag=0;
    try{
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPathm);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);
        //ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
        return ba1;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**I just want to know will my above code work to upload image to server**. thank you

Comment: no, your `uploadtoserver` method just encodes byte array to base64 string without uploading it anywhere, why do you want first to decode image to byte array and then make it even bigger by using base64?

Comment: okay so will above code convert the image to base64 string @pskink

Comment: what for? get typical jpeg of size 100k, when decoded to bytearray it will have 1M and then after encoding to base64 it will have 1.33M, the question is: what for? you want you app to be as slow as possible?

Comment: look what I am doing is I am already compressed the image I just want to save image server side only. @pskink

Comment: so you dont want to upload it to server? i am lost actually...

Comment: I want to upload the image to server @pskink

Comment: so use a physical file pointed by `imgPathm` and upload it as it is, why at all would you like to call `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` first?

Comment: will you please elaborate in answer because I am not getting you @pskink

Comment: you have some `MySuper.jpg` image, right? it has for example 100kB of size, so simply read those 100kB using `FileInputStream` and upload it wherever you like

Comment: To answer your original question: your code will not do anything with the image. Note that `bm` is set but never used after that.

Comment: @pskink would you please show how to use FileInputStream to upload image please

Comment: sure, this is how to use java [IO streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html)

Comment: @pskink it will be more helpful if you show some codes

Comment: the link I posted has a lot of sample code